# Why does switching power supply output AC

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply

I've been trying to troubleshoot some a 3D printer. It wouldn't power up. I checked the power supply ([NES-350-24](https://www.meanwell.com/Upload/PDF/NES-350/NES-350-SPEC.PDF)). The positive and negative outputs measured 0VDC, and 8VAC rms (confirmed with o-scope). I figured it should be outputting DC, and that the supply must be broken. I replaced it with a similar PS ([LRS-350-24](https://www.meanwell.com/Upload/PDF/LRS-350/LRS-350-SPEC.PDF)). Connected it to 120VAC power, and the outputs are still 8VAC RMS (60Hz).
Is this supply behaving normally? Is there some other issue? What am I overlooking? I would very much like to understand better what the issue is here, but I am no expert in these kinds of devices.

Edit: The new supply appears to be working as expected. I am still not able to ascertain the reason for the failure of the old supply. There are no obviously burned out components. Thank you all for your input.

Comment: Sounds like you are measuring Y-capacitor leakage. Does the AC voltage drop to 0 if you load it with something?

Comment: The data sheet clearly says DC voltage for the output.  If you’re seeing AC then I’d suggest you start by checking that the 0V of the PSU output is connected to your ‘scope ground, and whether the AC disappears when you remove AC power from the PSU.  You should certainly be seeing DC on the output.

Comment: Are you measuring betweeen the output terminals and Frame Ground (terminal 3)?  The DC output should be isolated from the AC input, and from the Frame Ground.  Measure the output voltage between the two groups of output terminals - terminals 7, 8, and 9 should be 24V positive relative to terminals 4, 5, and 6.

Comment: Hey, to check a PSU you should disconnect the normal load and place a known test load. The rest of your printer can behave in an unexpected way - for ex to take too much current continuously or too high current pulses. BTW did you measure the output voltage or voltage between one output and the case?

Comment: @Peter Bennet, I am measuring the +V and -V with respect to ground. When I measure between +V (7,8,9) and -V (4,5,6), the voltage is 0.

Comment: @user287001, I have the power supply completely removed from the printer, and directly plugged into the wall. There is no load attached.

Comment: When there is 0 between V+ and V- the supply is just not working. You should replace it. (or if You have knoweledge and experience - repair it). 8V AC with respect to ground is just random value due to the transformer capacitance and (probably existing) capacitor between mains rectified ground (not earth ground) and secondary side. Measuring supply output with respect to the earth is useless, becauose most smps are isolated from earth (computer atx and laptop psu's are not for example)

Comment: You MUST measure the output voltage BETWEEN THE OUTPUT TERMINALS.  The voltage between either output terminal and Frame Ground is irrelevant,because the output is isolated from Frame Ground.

Comment: @fifi_22 and Peter, thank you. I've measured the old supply and the new supply, they both register 0V between the output terminals. I find it hard to accept that the new PS is broken in the exact same way, perhaps there is a common design flaw? Seems more likely I am overlooking something basic. What would wiring the neutral to the ground terminal do?

Comment: How are You connecting input of the supply? NEVER ground/earth neutral. Why? Live and Neutal can be exchanged when using non-keyed plug or are messed up in the outlet itself. Treat neutral like live. Would You earth live?

Comment: Adding a connections schematic/photo would be useful. What psu that is?

Comment: @fifi_22 I figured connecting neutral to ground was not a good idea. Thank you.

Comment: Check you multimeter. Two devices, same trouble is not normal.

Comment: @user263983 I've checked with a multimeter and an o-scope.

Comment: Also measure if mains voltage is making it onto the PSU's terminals. Perhaps your outlet, test cord, etc... has a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the right way to measure the PSU output is directly across its terminals with a voltmeter, not a scope to ground. Verify you have output this way.

Now, about that AC voltage. It's normal, and it a characteristic of supplies like this have have an *isolated secondary*. What that means is, the output floats with respect to the line input and to earth (safety) ground. Meanwhile, the primary line/neutral connects to frame ground through a special capacitor called a Y cap. The PSU datasheet shows this in the diagram.

In the ideal case the primary-to-secondary isolation is complete: there is no circuit between earth or line and the power supply outputs. The output is said to be *floating*, and can have any offset with respect to ground.

In reality there is some coupling between the line input primary that appears on the secondary output that happens through the DC-DC transformer. This will show up as a common-mode AC voltage on the output, when measured using a high-impedance tester, measured from outputs to earth ground. This AC voltage is called **leakage**, and is usually under 5mA max for a typical supply (medical supplies are lower).

If this small leakage is a problem for your system, you can ground the secondary to earth (safety) ground.

On the other hand, **Never connect safety ground to neutral!** The two inputs (L1 and Neutral) could be swapped, resulting in a hot chassis and an unsafe system.